# need to concate all the rows of a string column to a single row in Informatica SQL WOrksheet

Tags: sql, sql-server, informatica

i need to use similar function like WM_CONCAT (in oracle)  to be used in SQL worksheet(Informatica)

e.g

```
<COlumm>
------
val1
val2
val3
val4
```

after concat :output shud be

```
<Column>
-------
val1,val2,val3,val4
```

that is String concat.

Comment: `STRING_AGG()` is what you're looking for

Comment: This questions should not be closed. This is Informatica related and not a SQL server question unless OP thinks he can do this in SQL server. Now in informatica, you can do this- Mapping should be like this SRC-->SQ-->SRT-->EXP-->AGG-->TGT. SRT on key_column. in exp, create 5 ports - key_col
val
v_val= iif(key_col !=v_key_col,val,v_val||' '||val)
v_key_col = key_col o_val=v_val     -- in the agg, pick max( o_val) group by key_col

Comment: its for Informatica Data Vault SQL Worksheet related syntax that i am searching for to achieve the requriement

Comment: hmm, pls try above solution and let me know if its fine.

Comment: m nt sure how to apply it, the pblm is i have a query which displays 5 columns, out of that the 5th column value is comming from a sub query... now since subquery should return only 1 row, we used wm_concat function is oracle that concatenates all the values and shows in 1 row.      this i want to do kn sql worksheet.... bt wm_concat aggregate function is not available.